# Flutter Firebase IOS token generation Issue on Testflight Real devices

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing the FCM based flutter application. In Android devices the FCM push notification is working without any issue. The same thing is not working in the IOS device. Specifically the FCM token not gets generated in the real device (TestFlight). But in IOS simulator the token gets generated.

Tried APNS (Apple Push Notification Service)